# Find max value from coalesce function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
declare @t table (date1 date,date2 date,date3 date)

insert into @t values ('2019-01-01','2019-01-20','2019-02-10')
insert into @t values (null,null,'2019-02-01')
insert into @t values (null,'2019-02-01','2019-02-02')
```

My expected output is:

```
2019-02-10  
2019-02-01  
2019-02-02
```

I tried to use coalesce like :

```
select coalesce(date1,date2,date3) as maxdate from @t
```

I know coalesce returns first not null value. So what I can do to get my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coalesce()` has nothing to do with this.  Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `greatest()`.  But you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, m.max_date
from @t t cross apply
     (select max(dte) as max_date
      from (values (t.date1), (t.date2), (t.date3)) v(dte)
     ) m;
```

The `max()` ignores `NULL` values, so this does what you expect.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8fb968f05dda6283f43e612f4de11427) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: what does this code means: select max(dte) as max_date
      from (values (date1), (date2), (date3)) v(dte)

Comment: @RedDevil . . . I'm not sure what you are asking.  It is calculating the maximum value from a derived table with three rows, one for each date.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick.

Basically you transform every row in a data-set, using `VALUES` clause, and then just get the MAX value.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate)
    FROM (VALUES (date1),(date2),(date3)) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate)) AS LastUpdateDate
FROM @t
```

Comment: Can you please explain the inner query? how is it working

Comment: @RedDevil Here is a link that helped me in the past :) https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/06/sql-server-creating-dataset-using-values-clause-without-creating-a-table/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would normalise your data, by unpivoting it, and then getting the `MAX` in the group. This *does*, however, require you have some kind of column to identify the row (I use an `IDENTITY` in this example):

```
DECLARE @t table (id int IDENTITY,
                  date1 date,
                  date2 date,
                  date3 date);

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ('2019-01-01', '2019-01-20', '2019-02-10');
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2019-02-01');
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (NULL, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-02');

SELECT MAX([date])
FROM @t t
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(t.date1),(date2),(t.date3))V([date])
GROUP BY t.id;
```